# responsive radio button in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to built a simple quiz in CSS without using javascript, I have written this code but please tell how can I apply action listener on radio button without using javascript? like if correct option is selected then a message "Correct" should be printed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Quiz</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h3>Capital of USA is?</h3>
  <input type="radio" value="opt1" name="capital">New York<br>
  <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="capital">Washington<br>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't. Doing things like this is what JavaScript does.

Comment: I don't see reason for downvote. One should allowed to ask even basic questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bit of hack for this

> Note:this might not be a good solution,this is the best that css can do

```css
label {
  display: none;
}
input:checked +br+ label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <h3>Capital of USA is?</h3>
<input type="radio" value="opt1" name="capital">New York
<br>
<label>Wrong answer</label>
<input type="radio" value="opt2" name="capital">Washington
<br>
<label>Right answer</label>
```